# request wcf Web service with postman

Tags: c#, soap, soapui, postman

i am trying to request WCF web service but i am getting error 500 with this message

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:messageSet. The InnerException message was 'Element Value from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.

if you know what should i do please help
thanks

[my request xml img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAIqe.png)

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <tem:QueryMessage>
        <tem:messageSet>
            <san:ActionId>?</san:ActionId>
            <san:Ip>::1</san:Ip>
            <san:Parameters>
                  <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Username</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>tipex</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>

                 <san:Parameter>
                    <san:Name>Password</san:Name>
                    <san:Value>123456</san:Value>
                </san:Parameter>

            </san:Parameters>
            <san:Title>Authenticate</san:Title>
            <san:Token>?</san:Token>
            <san:Username>?</san:Username>
        </tem:messageSet>
    </tem:QueryMessage>
</x:Body>
```

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:messageSet. The InnerException message was 'Element Value from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: Hi, can you [edit] your question to include the XML you are posting?

Comment: yes i will do it now wait a second

Comment: this image link show the request xml

Comment: Image links are no good - post the XML in the question (not an image).

Comment: this is my xml request

Comment: Ah... ok.. you say it's an WCF service; can you post the data contract object as well? then we can see the concretes you are trying to bind with.

Comment: note: here is a similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7abe3a8b-fdb8-460a-96bd-7f76b4ab7567/element-cannot-have-child-contents-to-be-deserialized-as-an-object

Comment: This is rather fragmented, do you have C# DataContract and/or ServiceContract classes to post?

Comment: @Stefan I don'n have access to back end i just have the service url !!!! 
any idea???

Comment: @bommelding unfortunately no !!! i have only the service url :(

Comment: Also try SoapUI, maybe it works better.

Comment: @bommelding i tried but the same issue is exist :(

Comment: Hmmm... tricky... maybe you should contact the provider.... they should be able to fix you an example

Comment: @Stefan yes I think so anyway thanks dude for your time

Comment: @HesamIlyaei: you're welcome.

Comment: @Archer do you have any idea???

Comment: Yes - what @Stefan said.  It may well just be a miss-match with the method signature, but without access to the server application you can't really say